# How can I limit wagtail's site history by site to support multi-tenancy?

Tags: multi-tenant, wagtail, audit-logging

I have a multi-tenant wagtail set up and we are currently working on getting up to date. We've just recently upgraded to [v2.15 which introduced audit logging for all models](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.15.html#audit-logging-for-all-models) instead of just page models.

AFAICT from looking through the [wagtail code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.15.6/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py#L4031), the changes for a page model are only visible to superusers or admins with `can_add_subpage` or `can_edit` permissions which seems to effectively support multi-tenancy.

However, for [all the other models](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.15.6/wagtail/core/models/audit_log.py#L112) there is no limitation put into effect. This means that an admin for Site A is seeing when changes are made to Site B or anytime a user is added or edited. We are using email addresses as usernames so this presents a rather major privacy issue.

This method hasn't been updated in any newer version, AFAICT, so I don't believe that just upgrading will fix this.

Does anyone have any ideas on either any wagtail settings we can change to keep Site and user changes invisible to non superusers or how we might localize `BaseLogEntryManager.viewable_by_user` so we can override the default wagtail implementation to our needs?

We have previously done something somewhat similar with the search available to admins by creating our own `src/app/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/search.html` and creating our own local version of https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/2.13.x/wagtail/admin/views/pages/search.py

I had thought about trying to do something similar here however that doesn't seem like a good thing to do given how different those circumstances are and I think it was only possible using the `register_admin_search_area` hook.

Answer (score 0):

I run a fairly large multitenanted Wagtail site. I have made [public gist of the code we use in Wagtail 2.16 to restrict reports](https://gist.github.com/cnk/0e220e7ce4796235e6fbc8efb1e15611).

One of the main things we had to patch is the filters on the reports page. We do not want users on one site to even know there are other users in the system. This is implemented in the site_specific_get_users_for_filter method.

Although our non-page models all have site_ids, it was not possible to filter ModelLogEntries in site, so we settled for hiding that report from everyone except superusers.